# Zooming to layers is not consistent

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am loading points using processing toolbox script and after loading the layers trying to zoom to the extent:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """

        api_key =  parameters['API_KEY']
        location_str = parameters['location']

        response = g.geocode(location_str, api_key)
        layer_extents = []
        if response:
            parsed_response = g.parse_response(response)
            for object in parsed_response:
                layer_extent = self.create_layer(object)
                layer_extents.append(layer_extent)
                
        # Initialize a QgsRectangle
        combined_extent = QgsRectangle()

        # Combine each extent into the overall extent
        for extent in layer_extents:
            combined_extent.combineExtentWith(extent)
        print(combined_extent)
        # Set the extent on the map canvas
        map_canvas.setExtent(combined_extent)
        # Refresh the canvas to update the view
        map_canvas.refresh()
                
        return {'output': 'geocoded'}
```

Idk know why, the zoom-to-layer works only to the first attempt after relaunching the qgis, and re-running the script does not zoom in to the new layer's extent. I am loading layers to the RAM

Comment: This is becoming a very common QGIS question on GISSE. The problem is that you have non-thread-safe api calls inside your `processAlgorithm()` method. Please read [The Tip given here highlighted in green](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags). You will definitely need to re-implement the `flags()` method in your script and `return QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading`.

Comment: @BenW thanks for your response. After your comment I have tried to put the def flags(self) after the def processAlgorithm, unfortunately, nothing has changed...